# Programmable timer in Kivy and Python

Tags: python, kivy, touch

I'm pretty new to Python and even more new to Kivy. My goal is to make a timer which I can set beforehand (which later shall control the GPIOs of my Raspberry, but that's another topic). I'm not really sure how I can do that. This ist my code so far:

Python Code: (Left away most imports for more cleanness)

```
import Global

Builder.load_file("screens.kv")


class ScreenOne(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenThree(Screen):

    def pressPlus(self):
        Global.DTIME = Global.DTIME + 0.5
        self.ids.lbl1.text = str(Global.DTIME) + "h"

    def pressMinus(self):
        if Global.DTIME > 0:
            Global.DTIME = Global.DTIME - 0.5
        else:
            pass
        self.ids.lbl1.text = str(Global.DTIME) + "h"

    def showTime(self):
        self.ids.lbl1.text = str(Global.DTIME) + "h"



    def printTime(self):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        print(app.TIME)

class Manager(ScreenManager):

    screen_one = ObjectProperty(None)
    screen_two = ObjectProperty(None)
    screen_three = ObjectProperty(None)


class Trockner(App):


    def build(self):
        m = Manager(transition=WipeTransition())
        return m

    def furz(self, *args):
        print("Fuuuuurz")






Trockner().run()
```

.kv File:

```
<ScreenOne>:
     Button:
          text: "Manuell"
          on_press:
               root.manager.current = 'screen2'
               app.furz()
          size_hint: 0.15, 0.15
          pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.075, 'center_y': 0.9225}
     Button:
          text: "Zeiteingabe"
          on_press:
               root.manager.current = 'screen3'
          size_hint: 0.15, 0.15
          pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.25, 'center_y': 0.9225}

     Label:
          #text: "Eingestellte Zeit: "
          id: lbl1
          size_hint: 0.15, 0.15
          pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.9225}

<ScreenTwo>:
     Button:
          text: "Automatik"
          on_press: root.manager.current = 'screen1'
          size: 100, 100
          size_hint: None, None
          pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.075, 'center_y': 0.9}

<ScreenThree>:
     FloatLayout:
          Label:
               id: lbl1
               size_hint:[.5,.5]
               pos_hint: {'right':1, 'top':1}
               font_size: 100
          Button:
               text: "+"
               size_hint:[.5,.5]
               on_press:
                    root.pressPlus()

          Button:
               text: "-"
               size_hint:[.5,.5]
               pos_hint: {'right': 1}
               on_press:
                    root.pressMinus()

          Button:
               text: "Enter"
               size_hint:[.5,.5]
               pos_hint: {'top':1, 'left':1}
               on_press:
                    root.manager.current = 'screen1'

<Manager>:
     id: screen_manager

     screen_one: screen_one
     screen_two: screen_two
     screen_three: screen_three

     ScreenOne:
          id: screen_one
          name: 'screen1'
          manager: screen_manager

     ScreenTwo:
          id: screen_two
          name: 'screen2'
          manager: screen_manager

     ScreenThree:
          id: screen_three
          name: 'screen3'
          manager: screen_manager
```

Right now, the Global.py which I'm importing is only holding the DTIME variable, so I can access it from Python and Kivy.

Plan is, that on Screen Three I can set a time which is then used on screen one again to start my countdown timer from set time. I also have to have access to the set time from my python code to switch the GPIOs after said time. The timer progress should also be visible on screen one then, which probably works with Kivy clock and animation. But I'm not really sure about that either, so help would be very much appreciated!